# pvPortMalloc and vPortFree Usage (freeRTOS Heap4.c) in Baremetal STM32F4x

Tags: heap-memory, freertos

I have had a good experience in programming bare metal stm32f4x; however, i tried to shift my code to freeRTOS and for that i first wanted to see if i can use Heap4.c for memory allocation instead of standard C malloc and free calls to better manage the memory etc.

However, what I observed is that using these calls disables my interrupts and never turns them back on. Hence, anything which makes use of interrupts is not working; everything else, which has nothing to do with interrupts is working ok. Not even Systick timer interrupt handler is being triggered.

So, the question is that, how can we make use of pvPortMalloc and vPortFree with bare metal code considering that all other peripherals do make use of their interrupts and SysTick is basically used for simple time delays etc. When using these calls, I could not see any prints happening inside systick as there was no systick handler being called.

Here I would like to point out that I am not calling pvPortMalloc or vPortFree in any interrupt context at all. So, that is totally safe and nothing to worry about that.

I have read through few discussions and if i understand correctly, then any call to FreeRTOS scheduler to suspend tasks etc does not impact as there will be no tasks at all. So, I expect this heap4.c port to work just fine with bare metal as well as long as we stay away from using them within ISR context; but apparently it just disables interrupts and seem to never turn them back on.

I hope to have the opinion of experts here on using pvPortMalloc and vPortFree in bare metal instead of using freeRTOS.

Best regards,
Junaid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you replace the xTaskSuspendAll() and xTaskResumeAll() to simply disable / enable interrupts it should work fine. In fact if your interrupts are not using the allocated memory you might not even need to do this, you could simply comment them out. Suspend and Resume are quite complex functions that can attempt to yield control to other tasks if required.

I suspect the reason interrupts are not getting re-enabled is that either taskEXIT_CRITICAL() is not defined correctly (portENABLE_INTERRUPTS) or the uxCriticalNesting is greater than one when truing to re-enable interrupts (enter critical called more times than exit critical).

However you will probably find the standard malloc and free are better if you are not using FreeRTOS.

Comment: Commenting out suspend and resume did fix the issue. However; I would like to say that standard malloc and free are by no means as good as pvPortMalloc and vPortFree. I have thoroughly tested this and I could encounter memory fragmentation quite easily. And, with the freeRTOS heap4.c I could avoid such memory fragmentation and make better use of available memory which is key in medium scale microcontrollers.